# How can I make sure the timer is set to half 4 every day, so I don't have to mention a certain date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, countdown, countdowntimer, jquery-countdown

How can I make sure the timer is set to half 4 every day, so I don't have to mention a certain date in Javascript? Also how is it possible to display the output in a div or p instead of form.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery Countdown</title>
</head>

<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function getTime() {
        now = new Date();
        orderBy = new Date("May 17 2016 16:30:00");
        //days = (orderBy - now) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        daysRound = Math.floor(days);
        hours = (orderBy - now) / 1000 / 60 / 60 - (24 * daysRound);
        hoursRound = Math.floor(hours);
        minutes = (orderBy - now) / 1000 /60 - (24 * 60 * daysRound) - (60 * hoursRound);
        minutesRound = Math.floor(minutes);
        seconds = (orderBy - now) / 1000 - (24 * 60 * 60 * daysRound) - (60 * 60 * hoursRound) - (60 * minutesRound);
        secondsRound = Math.round(seconds);
        sec = (secondsRound == 1) ? "" : "";
        min = (minutesRound == 1) ? " : " : " : ";
        hr = (hoursRound == 1) ? " : " : " : ";
        //dy = (daysRound == 1)  ? " day" : " days, ";
        document.timeForm.input1.value = "Check again before " + hoursRound + hr + minutesRound + min + secondsRound + sec;
        newtime = window.setTimeout("getTime();", 1000);
    }
    window.onload=getTime;

    if (days = 0){
        days.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>

<form name=timeForm>
    <input type=text name=input1 size=50 border-style="none" style="display: block; border: none; font-size: 14px; font-family: sans-serif">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Generally, if you  want something to happen on certain times, you'd use servertime for that, as the user can easily change the clock on his/her computer.

Comment: Could you place a demo on what you mean here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery Countdown</title>
</head>

<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 function getTime() {
  now = new Date();

  /*
   Use todays date to calculate tomorrows alarm
  */

  var day = now.getDate()
  /*console.log('today: ' + day)*/

  var monthsAbbrev = [
   "Jan",
   "Feb",
   "Mar",
   "Apr",
   "May",
   "June",
   "July",
   "Aug",
   "Sept",
   "Oct",
   "Nov",
   "Dec"
  ];
  var index = now.getMonth()
  var month = monthsAbbrev[ index ]
  /*console.log('month: ' + month)*/

  var year = now.getFullYear()
  /*console.log('year: ' + year)*/




  var monthsWith31days = [
   "Jan",
   "Mar",
   "May",
   "July",
   "Aug",
   "Oct",
   "Dec"
  ];

  var monthsWith30days = [
   "Apr",
   "June",
   "Sept",
   "Nov"
  ];


  var alarm = "04:30:00 PM"
  var time = now.toLocaleTimeString() /* "HH:MM:ss AM/PM" */
  /*console.log('time: ' + time)
  console.log('is it true??' + (time >= alarm))*/
  if (time >= alarm) {
   console.log('today is ' + day)

   var maxIs31 = new RegExp("(" + monthsWith31days.join("|") + ")").test(month)
   var maxIs30 = new RegExp("(" + monthsWith30days.join("|") + ")").test(month)
   var monthIsFeb = /(Feb)/.test(month)

   /*console.log('maxIs31: ' + maxIs31)
   console.log('maxIs30: ' + maxIs30)
   console.log('monthIsFeb: ' + monthIsFeb)*/

   if (maxIs31) {
    (day >= 31) ? (day = 1) : ( day +=1 )
   } else if (maxIs30) {
    (day >= 30) ? (day = 1) : ( day +=1 )
   } else if (monthIsFeb) {
    if (parseInt(year, 10) % 4 === 0) {
     /* its a leap year */
     (day >= 29) ? (day = 1) : ( day += 1 )
    } else {
     (day >= 28) ? (day = 1) : ( day += 1 )
    }
   }
   console.log('tomorrow wil be?? ' + day)
  }


  /*

   Now set tomorrows alarm only if its gone off today
   */
  orderBy = new Date( month +" "+ day +" "+ year +" "+ alarm );


  days = (orderBy - now) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
  daysRound = Math.floor(days);
  hours = (orderBy - now) / 1000 / 60 / 60 - (24 * daysRound);
  hoursRound = Math.floor(hours);
  minutes = (orderBy - now) / 1000 /60 - (24 * 60 * daysRound) - (60 * hoursRound);
  minutesRound = Math.floor(minutes);
  seconds = (orderBy - now) / 1000 - (24 * 60 * 60 * daysRound) - (60 * 60 * hoursRound) - (60 * minutesRound);
  secondsRound = Math.round(seconds);
  sec = (secondsRound == 1) ? "" : "";
  min = (minutesRound == 1) ? " : " : " : ";
  hr = (hoursRound == 1) ? " : " : " : ";
  //dy = (daysRound == 1)  ? " day" : " days, ";
  document.timeForm.input1.value = "Check again before " + hoursRound + hr + minutesRound + min + secondsRound + sec;
  newtime = window.setTimeout("getTime();", 1000);
 }
 window.onload=getTime;

 if (days = 0){
  days.style.display = "none";
 }
</script>

<form name="timeForm">
 <input type="text" name="input1" size="50" border-style="none" style="display: block; border: none; font-size: 14px; font-family: sans-serif">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```